# Memory access and cache

Tags: c++, memory

When is the CPU Data Cache updated?
Take these situations as examples:

Example 1:

```
SomeObject* pObject; 
//[...]
pObject->member = variable;
```

Example 2:

```
SomeObject object; 
object.member = variable;
```

How is cache updated in those examples?
Is it the same? Or are there differences in terms of data access because example 1 uses a pointer and example 2 doesnt?

Comment: `pObject->member = variable;`. It's either stack or heap. What is the cache thing ?

Comment: What cache? What is a `D-Cache`?

Comment: `SomeObject* pObject = new SomeObject();`
`pObject->member = variable;`

Comment: D-cache = Data Cache. And the answer will depend on what the object is and where it is stored...

Comment: Are you talking about the CPU cache?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin it was a typo sorry

Comment: depend on how cpu is designed, how the compiler optimized the code, etc.

Comment: If you're seriously interested in cache effects I strongly recommend finding a copy of [Curt Schimmel's UNIX® Systems for Modern Architectures: Symmetric Multiprocessing and Caching for Kernel Programmers](http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Systems-Modern-Architectures-Multiprocessing/dp/0201633388/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1318754319&sr=8-1). The main change since the time the book was written is our CPUs today have as much cache as we had RAM back then, but I think the rest held up very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *example 1*, CPU first needs to access the pointer itself, then the actual object.

- Pointer is on the stack which gives it a good chance it is already in data cache due good locality with other variables on the stack. It might even be in register.
- It is unusual for the object to be on the same stack frame as pointer - it is either on the heap (on "random" location) or on a shallower stack frame, and there is a possibility it is no longer in d-cache so you are more likely to pay memory latency penalty.

In *example 2*, CPU can access the object directly, which is on the stack so it has a good chance it is already cached due good locality with to other variables on the stack.

All the memory locations accessed will end-up in d-cache until replaced by more recently accessed locations. How exactly is d-cache maintained and synchronized between different cores in  multi-core CPU is implementation detail of a particular CPU and involves "cache lines" (typically 64-bit blocks that are "units" of caching) and various cache coherence protocols.

That being said, you should be aware of a serious degradation of performance in multi-threaded environment that may be consequence of these implementation details, called [false sharing](http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=217500206).

Generally speaking, chasing pointers is slower than just accessing memory linearly, because it has worse locality (so caches are less effective) and worse predictability (so CPU cannot utilize prefetching effectively).

Comment: What if pSomeObject and variable are in distant places of memory? Can they be in cache at the same time or one after another?

Comment: @TiagoCosta Yes they can (be in cache at the same time). They will be in different "cache lines".

Comment: Oh I see... Can you recommend me some book that explains how caches work? I've read Intel programming guidelines but they aren't very helpful because they're too high-level

Comment: Sorry Tiago, I can't - I didn't learn it from any particular book myself, I gathered this knowledge from many sources over the years. That being said, if you are seriously interested in performance, I warmly recommend seeing some of Herb Sutter's lectures, for example: "Machine Architecture: Things Your Programming Language Never Told You" at http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4714369049736584770 and http://www.nwcpp.org/Downloads/2007/Machine_Architecture_-_NWCPP.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It depends largely on how it gets compiled and the architecture you're using. If you want better cache performance, try to minimize unnecessary bloat and access sequentially.

```
SomeObject* pObject; 
pObject->member = variable;
```

`pObject` the pointer, `pObject->member`, and `variable` should end up in the cache.

```
SomeObject object; 
object.member = variable;
```

`object`(all of its members used in constructor) and `variable` should end up in the cache.

Comment: If the optimizer put any of those in registers, they won't end up in the cache.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Good point, I've changed the wording slightly.